# Error while testing React component using Jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I kept getting this error while testing a react component:

> Error: Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(..., .0): Unable to find
>   element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g.,
>   by the browser), usually due to forgetting a <tbody> when using
>   tables, nesting tags like <form>, <p>, or <a>, or using non-SVG
>   elements in an <svg> parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the
>   element with React ID ``.

Code I used to test:

```
describe(`Method: flattenData`, () => {

  const tests = [
    {
      toFlatten: {
        'key1': 'k',
        'key2': 'n',
        'key3': 'o'
      },
      expectedResult: 'key1: k; key2: n; key3: o'
    }
  ];

  tests.forEach((test) => {

    expect(instance.flattenData(test.toFlatten)).toEqual(test.expectedResult);

   });

});
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about the `instance` variable you're referencing? Is the error occurring when you call `instance.flattenData` or when you create the instance of your component?

Comment: I found the fix, I didn't provide any more data about instance by mistake, and instance.flattenData was not relevant in this case. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this bug by adding a parameter to the render call. This forces the component (which is just a `<td> </td>` to be rendered inside a table.

Before:

```
[container, instance] = render(TableCell, {
  data: `content`,
  dataTh: `content`,
  key: `content`,
  dataLocator: `content`
});
```

With the fix:

```
[container, instance] = render(TableCell, {
  data: `content`,
  dataTh: `content`,
  key: `content`,
  dataLocator: `content`
}, `table`);
```